# facebook comments notification

Tags: facebook, comments, notify

I have added the html5 version of facebook comments to my webpage successfully. Now I'm trying to work out how to be notified of new comments as per the documentation. I added this code to the script which goes at the top under the body.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
function(response) {
    comment.create{
    href: "",         /* Open Graph URL of the Comment Plugin */
    commentID: "",    /* The commentID of the deleted comment */
    }
  }
);
```

a) Is my code correct
b) I am not sure exactly where to add the code
c) I am also using the html5 version of the comments plugin, do I perhaps need to use the xfbml version?
d) Do i need to replace any code within the commented area or is this handled automatically by facebook? i.e. add a href url etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should replace 'edge.create' with ['comment.create'](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/).
2. I personally didn't tried the HTML5 version yet, but if you want I wrote a [**tutorial**](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=74644) for this in the XFBML version.